# One Hot Encoding with Sparse categorical entropy throwing error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, mnist, one-hot-encoding

So I am doing the MNIST Fashion example for Keras. And in the program I wrote for it, I didn't need to use "to_categorical" to one hot encode my data, and it still worked. When i tried to one hot encode it, it did not work. I am confused why this happened, because usually one should one hot encode their outputs right? If someone could help clarify this that would be great!

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Activation
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from kerastuner import RandomSearch
import time
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters


LOG_DIR = f"{int(time.time())}"

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
#

#
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, x_train.shape[0], 28, 28)
    input_shap2 = (1, x_test.shape[0], 28, 28)
else:
    input_shape = (x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
    input_shap2 = (x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
y_test = to_categorical(y_test) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

# plt.imshow(x_train[0], cmap='gray')
# plt.show()

x_train = x_train.reshape(input_shape)
x_test = x_test.reshape(input_shap2)


def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(hp.Int("input_units", min_value=32, max_value=256, step=32), (3, 3), input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    for i in range(hp.Int("n_layers", 1, 4)):
        model.add(Conv2D(hp.Int(f"conv_{i}_units", min_value=32, max_value=256, step=32), (3, 3)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        # model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))

    model.compile(optimizer="adam",
                  loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

# model=build_model()
# model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=8, validation_data = (x_test, y_test))

tuner = RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective="val_accuracy",
    max_trials=1,
    executions_per_trial=1,
    directory=LOG_DIR
)

tuner.search(
    x=x_train,
    y=y_train,
    epochs=1,
    batch_size=64,
    validation_data=(x_test,y_test)
)
```

Comment: will you please share some error along with code to get more clear picture

Comment: sorry im new here, will do immediately @SohaibAnwaar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using sparse-categorical-crossentropy instead of categorical-crossentropy. Sparse uses integer encoding whereas the other one uses one hot encoding. You should either use sparse and not one hot your labels, or use the other and one hot encode the labels

Comment: So now you got the solution. Thats good (Y) keep it up

Comment: @REEEEEE Does that mean all the inputs will be automatically sparse-one-hot encoded at the input side? shouldn't the first layers have enough neurons to encode each input? Else the NN might infer that continous integers at the input layer have a co-relation isn't it?

Comment: what if your labels are sparse but one hot encoded? I mean if you have mostly zeros and not many 1's ?